# Best way to consume javascript data blocks with react or web components?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, web-component, stenciljs

I will be working with legacy software built with Microsoft Behaviors, and Data Islands, both no longer supported since IE 10. The middle tier transforms xml data into "data-blocks" (JavaScript can use the content of a  element as a data block if the src attribute is omitted..). Unfortunately, there's a gazillion of these data blocks so a full-rewrite of the middle-tier or establishing a serverless architecture to interface with the backend is out of the question. A clean solution is eluding me, can anyone think of a way to reuse these existing data-blocks with a modern framework such as react, angular, vue, stencil (custom elements via web components)?

Comment: you should give an example

Comment: unfortunately, dont have anything just yet - im working off this - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Misc_top_level/Using_XML_Data_Islands_in_Mozilla. Ultimately, I understand that react has a virtual dom - and trying to figure out exactly how these data blocks are reconstructed inside of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to parse the content of your custom `<script>` Data Block into a XML document.

Since it is standard Javascript, you can use it in the framework of your choice.

Below is an example with a vanilla Custom Element that I called `<xml-renderer>`:

```js
class XMLRenderer extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' })
        .innerHTML = `<style> 
                        div { background-color: lightblue ; 
                              display: inline-block ;
                              padding : 10px ;}
                      </style>
                      <div>XML Content
                        <ul></ul>
                      </div>`
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    //get the data island id
    var _block_id = this.dataset.block
    var _ul = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('ul')
    var _xml

    parseXML()
    render()

    //internal methods
    //parse
    function parseXML() {
      var text = document.getElementById(_block_id)
      var parser = new DOMParser()
      _xml = parser.parseFromString(text.textContent, 'application/xml')
    }

    //render
    function render() {
      _xml.querySelectorAll('data').forEach(d => {
        let li = document.createElement('li')
        li.textContent = d.textContent
        _ul.appendChild(li)
      })
    }
  }

}
customElements.define("xml-renderer", XMLRenderer)
```

```html
<script type="application/xml" id="data-block1">
  <base><data>Data 1</data><data>Data 2</data></base>
</script>

<xml-renderer data-block="data-block1"></xml-renderer>
```

Comment: This is great, and exactly the sort of approach I wanted. Thanks much!

Comment: Thanks :-) Note that you could also put the script element inside the custom element itself

Comment: Neat! That's a tour de force on custom HTML elements. But I'm still trying to understand the point of using a "script" element. Wouldn't all of this same mechanism work just as well using any other kind of element? Is there anything special about it being a "script" element? (I suppose with "script" the browser doesn't try to display it. But if it's only that, couldn't you just as well do a "div" with "display:none"?)